# Add Azure WebJob to mobile service hosted in App Service

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

With the new Azure Mobile App Services in Azure the mobile services apparently gains the same WebJob support as Websites have had for a while.

Following the article [Deploy WebJobs using Visual Studio](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/) according to the section 'Enable automatic WebJobs deployment with a web project' we should be able to add a web job from a right click on the project. None of these options show up for my mobile service project in VS.

I can add a WebJob project to the solution manually, but this does not add the webjobs-list.json file to my mobile service project as the article suggests.

Does anyone know why the add web job context menu doesn't show when right-clicking on the mobile service project? Or the manual steps required to configure the project and appropriate webjobs-list.json file?

*Update:*
I have manually added the webjobs-list.json file to the main project by copying the format from another initial template project and adjusted the web job project path in it. Even deploying the mobile service to an azure web app doesn't pick up the web job.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I just created a new Mobile App, downloaded the quickstart, right-clicked the web project (`appname-code`), and was able to associate a webjob to the web project. Deployment worked as planned. Did you try that workflow? Did you try adding the webjob through the portal?

Comment: I was having issues with an existing project. I did the same (downloading the quick start) and seemed to work, but wondering why it wasn't working with my existing project.
I have updated Nuget references to the packages for the new App Services now and it gives me the option now. Must be something to do with the project packages. Will post again once tested more

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let me know if you hit any other issues.